# Keep video call alive during navigation

Tags: flutter

I am using [flutter-webrtc](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc) to create a video call application. I have `ScreenHome` , `ScreenCall` ,`ScreenA` and `ScreenB`
When new call established I push to `ScreenCall` , Consider the following navigator route stack :

```
ScreenHome -> `ScreenA` -> ScreenCall
```

When we are in `ScreenCall` we have two `RTCVideoView` widget to show local and remote videos, When the users press back and goes to `ScreenA` or by navigating again goes to another screen such as `ScreenB`, I want to keep call alive and play the sound (or may be video too) of the remote video in the background

How can I do this?

Comment: That's common case. Think of any music player. You can go anywhere, in any screen. The music will not stop.

Comment: is `RTCVideoView` play the sound? or just it play video?