# Move widget in widget tree

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to move a widget in widget tree?

Is it possible to move a widget (i.e `ElevatedButton`) from `SecondRoute` to `FirstRoute` once the `SecondRoute` is disposed? I know it's weird but I just want to know is it possible in flutter and how?

Note: a use case can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67147456/6447123) I want to move `RTCVideoView` to an `Offstage` that presents in all routes

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can pass data with you while navigating and use it in the another screen to show or hide button thats there , I don't know what's the point of passing the ElevatedButton.

Comment: Yes it is. Just make a seperate widget and pass it like normal widget

Comment: @MoaidAL-Razhy It's just a question! take it easy

Comment: @ProblematicDude I want to really **Move** it, [use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67147456/keep-video-call-alive-during-navigation)

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 solutions

1. Create 2 separate widgets that perform the same action and put it in a Hero widget so it animates nicely between screens
2. If you must make it only 1 widget then you'll have to overlap your view (Scaffolds) with that widget with a Stack and handle it from upper in the tree

Comment: So you think that it is impossible to move a widget in widget tree and preserve it's state

Comment: You can preserve the state without the need to move the widget
You can have 10 Widgets doing the exact same action at the same time while listening to a single State management solution such as Provider

Comment: I am aware of state management and advanced in flutter, I told in question that it seams weird, in Vue.js we have `<keep-alive>` in react we have `react-keep-alive`